# Copy Macro into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on a project, but I'm not as versed with Macros , and even less versed in Scripts. I've created an entry form on sheet "PM Entry" and the Macro for the button, copies all the cells in an array and pastes them on another sheet "PM Tracking" in a new row, so I can start building data from the entries. The Macro, works perfectly. Uploading to Google Sheets, of course the Macros don't transfer.

The trouble I'm having is transcribing the code from Macro to Script. I've gotten it to work a couple times, but not consecutively. This is the macro, I'm trying to turn into a script

```
Sub SubmitButton()
    
    Dim DB As Worksheet, SH As Worksheet
    Dim TargetRow As Long, Index As Long
    Dim SourceArr As Variant, DestArr As Variant
    Dim Source As Range, Dest As Range
    
    'set reference up-front
    Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PM Entry")
    Set DB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PM Tracking")
    With DB
        TargetRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    SourceArr = Array("D5", "H5", "D7", "D9", "H7", "H9", "D15", "D16", "D18", "H15", "H16", "H18", "D24", "D25", "D27", "H24", "H25", "H27", "D34", "D35", "D37", "H34", "H35", "H37", "D43", "D44", "D46")
    DestArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA")
    
    'loop through the source array, copying cell values to DB sheet
    For Index = LBound(SourceArr) To UBound(SourceArr)
        Set Source = SH.Range(SourceArr(Index))
        Set Dest = DB.Range(DestArr(Index) & TargetRow)
        Source.Copy
        Dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Next Index
    
    End Sub
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like we need to start the new tag `VB to GAS translation`. It's a quite popular theme these days. Unfortunately I'm not versed in VB. I will try to figure it out though, if there is nobody to help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/macro-converter/overview

Comment: I do not recommend "translating", it is the worst way, because sometimes GSheets offers the possibility of formulas (query, arrayformula, filter). You have to explain what you are expecting and try to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just in case. Probably this code will do the job:

```
function copyData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PM Entry');
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PM Tracking');

  var cells = ["D5", "H5", "D7", "D9", "H7", "H9",
  "D15", "D16", "D18", "H15", "H16", "H18", "D24", "D25", "D27", 
  "H24", "H25", "H27",  "D34", "D35", "D37", 
  "H34", "H35", "H37", "D43", "D44", "D46"];

  var data = cells.map(c => sheet.getRange(c).getValue());

  dest_sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

Comment: You are my hero. Worked perfectly. Thank you!